# Spring Data Jpa join table query exclude a certain field

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For example, I have an Email table which contains **email_id**, **subject**, and **body** field. And I have an Attachment table which contains **attachment_id**, **email_id**, **attachment_name**, **attachment_type** and **raw_content** field. Raw_content is blob type and is used to store attachment. One email may have many attachments.

Now I create JPA entity like below:

**EmailEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
@Data
public class EmailEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "BODY")
    private String body;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "email", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<AttachmentEntity> attachmentEntityList;
    
}
```

**AttachmentEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attachment")
@Data
public class AttachmentEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_ID")
    private String attachmentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_CONTENT_ID")
    private EmailEntity email;

    @Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_NAME")
    private String attachmentName;

    @Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_TYPE")
    private String attachmentType;

    @Column(name = "RAW_CONTENT")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Blob rawContent;


}
```

Now I want to query email and its attachments **without** rawContent by email_id. Actually rawContent should be removed from the result. But I hope that the sql query will not check this field at all, because this field is very large and may be time-consuming. So how should I write the code? I tried extracting rawContent field separately into a class and extends AttachmentEntity. It works for query but it gives me a lot of trouble to perform database insert, because I cannot use save() method from EmailEntityRepository any more. What's the best practice for this case?

I expect there is a way to exclude a certain field in the entity in the query, but it does not affect the database insertion in JPA. My **exclude** means that the sql query statement does not execute the query of this field, rather than querying this field but being discarded actually.

Comment: JPA has the concept of eager and lazy fetching that you may want to look into - you can just mark this field as lazy and JPA will only fetch it if/when accessed (via getRawContent on the entity when it isn't detached). You can also control it being loaded with load graphs and (on more recent version of hibernate) not fetching it (if you are leaving it eager) with a fetch graph which leaves everything undefined within it as lazy loaded and so unfetched. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedEntityGraph.html but there are many tutorials describing them

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA has **Projections**, a tool that let you select you only specific fields from entities.

Projections required to define a new class/interface (so you are not going to get an actual `EmailEntity`, but a custom object `EmailEntityView` that has everything from `EmailEnity` and `AttachmentEntity` minus the `rawContent` field) so this can be an big constraint in some case.

There are lot of tutorial online, and it's not and hard comcept to understand and implements.

Comment: Spring projections is very similar to JPA constructor queries ("Select new projectionEntity(email.emailId, email.attachmentEntityList).."). If you try to get Spring to deal with the email.attachmentEntityList as a List instead of a different projectionEntity for every attachmentEntity in that list because of the *ToMany join, it will pull in the full entity and use that to build the projection entities: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1509 where they even mention they should have used JPA entity graphs but couldn't at the time.